# select a random range of curves within current selection

Tags: python, select, random

I am an absolute novice, but have a feeling this is an easy thing for someone who knows python.

Basically I have a group of nurbs curves selected, and what I want to do is randomize the selection with a specified range. For instance from a list of 100 curves, or basically whatever I have selected, give me a random random 50 back. Hope I made this clear enough.

All I've managed to get so far is printing a random curve within my selection.

```
import maya.cmds as m
import random
sel = m.ls(sl=True)
from random import choice
print choice(sel)
```

Comment: you should fix your post to show the code properly

Answer (score 1):

`random.choice(population)` gives you one random element from `population`.

`random.sample(population, k)` gives you a sampling of *k* elements from `population`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your problem's domain(maya?), but you can take samples with `random.sample`:

```
>>> from random import sample
>>> a = list(range(50))
>>> a
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49]
>>> sample(a, 10)
[6, 7, 9, 20, 17, 43, 24, 14, 22, 12]
```